# fatal error on loading URL in UIWebView in swift

Tags: swift, uiwebview, uistoryboard

I am using UISplitViewController to display ,master and detail page in **All Visible** mode. Potrait orientation only. I am using expandable table view in masterVC. So I add a view in section. If I tap that view, URL should be reflect in webView which in detailVC. But, to my code, I am receiving an error. I am not using any navigation controller for this. Directly I have connected splitViewController to master and detail view controller. I described below. Kindly help me.

**In Detail View Controller**

```
func webViewLoader()
    {
        println("Came Inside Web View")
        let url = "http://makeapppie.com/2014/10/28/swift-swift-using-uiwebviews-in-swift/"
        let requestURL = NSURL(string:url)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
        webView.loadRequest(request) //FATAL ERROR WHILE UNWRAPPING
    }
```

**In Master View Controller**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, sideTableView.frame.size.width, 49)) //ADDING VIEW TO SECTION - FOR EXPANDABLE TABLEVIEW
        var layerLine = CALayer()
        layerLine.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: headerView.frame.size.height, width:  headerView.frame.size.width, height: 1)
        layerLine.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 220/255, green: 220/255, blue: 220/255, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 242/255, green: 242/255, blue: 242/255, alpha: 1.0)
        headerView.tag = section

        headerView.layer.addSublayer(layerLine) //ADDING BOTTOM BORDER TO CELL

        let headerString = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: sideTableView.frame.size.width-10, height: 30)) as UILabel
        headerString.text = sideTblData.objectAtIndex(section) as! NSString as String
        headerString.font = headerString.font.fontWithSize(15)
        headerView .addSubview(headerString)

        let headerTapped = UITapGestureRecognizer (target: self, action: "sectionHeaderTapped:")
        headerView .addGestureRecognizer(headerTapped)
        return headerView
    }
```

**In sectionHeaderTapped**

```
func sectionHeaderTapped(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc : DetailVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("web-link") as! atlDetailVC
        vc.webViewLoader()
}
```

**In viewDidLoad**

```
let url = "http://makeapppie.com/2014/10/28/swift-swift-using-uiwebviews-in-swift/"
let requestURL = NSURL(string:url)
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
webView.loadRequest(request) //It is working. But, in method call, why I am getting fatal error??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a similar app but there is no problem with my code. This is my Code:

```
class MasterViewController: UITableViewController{
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let dvc = self.splitViewController?.viewControllers.last as! DetailViewController

        dvc.webViewLoader()
    }
}

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var WebView: UIWebView!

    func webViewLoader() {
        println("Came Inside Web View")
        let url = "http://www.google.com"
        let requestURL = NSURL(string:url)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
        WebView.loadRequest(request) //FATAL ERROR WHILE UNWRAPPING
    }
}
```

**Update 1**

I've Uploaded The [Project](https://www.mediafire.com/?txq34kh90kn6890)

Comment: Hi.. having doubt again? Cn u help me? @Hossein

Comment: Now I am using,, navigation controller,, Then,, how to get method of detailViewController??

Comment: navigation controller for which side? explain in detail

Comment: My Arch =>loginViewController=>splitViewController => NaviController => MasterVC,  splitViewController => NaviController => DetailVC

Comment: if you used a navigation controller for the detail side, you can access the DetailViewController with this: `(self.splitViewController?.viewControllers.last as! UINavigationViewController).topViewController as! DetailViewController`

Comment: Yes !! Got it.. 1 more doubt. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31307858/how-to-navigate-from-intial-uiviewcontroller-to-uisplitviewcontroller-in-swift

Comment: pls see this and help me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82788/discussion-between-hossein-maktoobian-and-mcdonal-11).