# How to Navigate from Initial UIViewController to UISplitViewController in Swift

Tags: swift, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller

I am showing my details in **UISplitViewController** in **AllVisible** mode. But, before that, **loginViewController** is there. User should login, then it will navigate **UISplitViewController.** I don't know how to navigate to that viewController. I am not using any **UINavigationController** inside my app. I have tried something, but failure. I used following code:

**Code:**

```
//ATTEMPT 1:
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("split", sender: self)

//ATTEMPT 2:
let leftVC = atlMasterVC()
let detailVC = atlDetailVC()
let splitViewController = splitVC()
splitViewController.viewControllers = [leftVC,detailVC]

//ATTEMPT 3
self.presentViewController(splitViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("split") as! splitVC
self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

If I am any wrong, kindly guide me.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing something wrong. I have no problem in my code and it goes to split view if the password is OK. Take a look at this:

**Story Board:** *Login -> Split -> (Master, Detail)*

[image]

**Login** *Has A Button, A Switch And A Segue Between Itself And Split View Controller (identifier: 'showsplit')*

**LoginViewController Class:**

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var pass: UISwitch!

    @IBAction func btn(sender: AnyObject) {
        if pass.on {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("showsplit", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi!! R u thr? Having another doubt. Its very impt for me. pls reply. I ll ask u.